# Unix random sort only on an internal key / column

Tags: bash, sorting, random, key, internal

How would you perform a Unix sort only on an internal column?

The following statement seems reasonable, but it unexpectedly forgets about the first randomization step: it produces the same output when repeated.

```
$ sort --random-sort test.txt | sort --key=2,2
1 a 2
2 a 1
1 b 2
2 b 1
```

btw, my interest is eventually to create stratified random samples (which first requires randomization and grouping).

Answer (score 1):

If you want some randomness to remain, you need to add the `--stable` option to the second sort:

```
$ sort --random-sort test.txt | sort --key=2,2 --stable
2 a 1
1 a 2
1 b 2
2 b 1
$ sort --random-sort test.txt | sort --key=2,2 --stable
1 a 2
2 a 1
1 b 2
2 b 1
```

This is documented by [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html):

> A pair of lines is compared as follows: sort compares each pair of
>   fields, in the order specified on the command line, according to the
>   associated ordering options, until a difference is found or no fields
>   are left. If no key fields are specified, sort uses a default key of
>   the entire line. **Finally, as a last resort when all keys compare
>   equal, sort compares entire lines as if no ordering options other than
>   --reverse (-r) were specified. The --stable (-s) option disables this last-resort comparison so that lines in which all fields compare equal
>   are left in their original relative order.** The --unique (-u) option
>   also disables the last-resort comparison.

In other words, in your case, if two lines compare the same under key=2,2, `sort` will, by default, ignore your key selection and compare the entire line.  By specifying `--stable`, the default behavior is suppressed and the original order is preserved for those lines.